# why is the infer keyword limited to conditionals? Why not generics?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Here’s an example of a use case for TypeScript’s `infer` keyword, an implementation of `ReturnType`:

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args:any) => any> = T extends (...args:any) => infer R ? R : never
```

Why is the conditional necessary here? Why can’t `infer` be used like this?

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args:any) => infer R> = R
```

This seems so much clearer and more concise to me, especially in cases where the `false` branch of the conditional is `never` because it’s not allowed based on previous type restrictions.

To be clear, I understand the reason is “because it doesn’t work that way in TypeScript”. I’m really asking, is there a clear, stated reason why it was designed this way? Is there a discussion thread out there I can read or something?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52791

Comment: This would be really useful when wrapping functions.